# How to find out details like operating system, architecture type for my browser in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing an API microservice is Node.js app. From GET Request, I want to find the os and arch type for my browser

For example --> "Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Express, what about writing your own middleware?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user_agent = req.get('User-Agent');
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to parse the [`User-Agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) HTTP header.

For Node.js, you can use [useragent](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/useragent).

Answer (score -1):

For the Operative System you can get it from os package:
https://nodejs.org/api/os.html

For detecting the browser you can get the 'user-agent' from the request headers